# ZEDGraph cannot change axis color

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Hi I am new to Zedgraph and I can only find few examples and information.
What I need to do is simple just change the color of the axes from default black to white.This is because I want to use black fill for my panes.
So I try the following

```
pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;
            pane.XAxis.Color = Color.White; ;
            pane.Y2Axis.Color = Color.White;
```

Strangely this seems to have no effect and my axis lines are still invisible(lost in the black fill).

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is right, but the axes are overlain by the chart border. So you have two options:
Either make the border invisible:

```
pane.Chart.Border.IsVisible = false;
```

Or set also the color of the border to white:

```
pane.Chart.Border.Color = Color.White;
```

But be aware, that

```
pane.XAxis.Color = Color.White;
```

only effects the axis-line. For coloring all elements of the axis, you also have to set the Colors of Title, Scale, MajorTic, MinorTic, MajorGrid, and MinorGrid of each axis (see [ZEDGraph API](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_Axis_Color.htm)).